# The imageview has moved out of the collection view cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionviewcell

I am new to iOS development and this is my first project that i am doing alone. i am trying to show the feed of my college's unofficial fb page using uicollectionview. I have been trying a lot of different things but nothing seems to work.The image view has moved out of the collectionviewcell
    UICollectionViewController.m file

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
self.title = @"DCE Speaks Up";
self.collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.95 alpha:1];
// Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
// self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
NSError *error= nil;

NSURL *feedURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/382057938566656/feed?fields=id,full_picture,message,story,created_time,link&access_token=1750413825187852%7CkUl9nlZFPvdGxGZX4WYabKKG2G4"];

NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:feedURL];

NSDictionary *dataDictionary= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];
self.feedArray = [NSMutableArray array];
NSArray *feedTempArray = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"data"];        //feedTempArray just used for parsing

for (NSDictionary *feedDictionary in feedTempArray) {
    FacebookFeed *fbFeed =[FacebookFeed facebookFeedWithMessage:[feedDictionary objectForKey:@"message"]];
    fbFeed.story = [feedDictionary objectForKey:@"story"];
    fbFeed.imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[feedDictionary objectForKey:@"full_picture"]];
    fbFeed.date = [feedDictionary objectForKey:@"created_time"];
    fbFeed.sharedLink = [NSURL URLWithString:[feedDictionary objectForKey:@"link"]];
    [self.feedArray addObject:fbFeed];
}



// Register cell classes
[self.collectionView registerClass:[FacebookCollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
```

}

```
 - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
FacebookCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.feed = self.feedArray[indexPath.row];
cell.sizeDictionary = [self sizeForLabelAtIndexPath:indexPath.row collectionView:collectionView];
// Configure the cell
for (UIView *view in cell.contentView.subviews) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }else if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]){
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
    cell.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;          
    cell.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
return cell;
}
#pragma mark <UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>
-(CGSize) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSDictionary *sizeDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
    sizeDictionary = [self sizeForLabelAtIndexPath:indexPath.row collectionView:collectionView];
        return CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width - 20, [sizeDictionary[@"imageHeight"] floatValue] + [sizeDictionary[@"messageHeight"] floatValue] + [sizeDictionary[@"nameHeight"] floatValue]);
}
#pragma mark <UICollectionViewDelegate>
- (NSDictionary *) sizeForLabelAtIndexPath:(NSUInteger)indexPath collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView{
FacebookFeed *feed = self.feedArray[indexPath];
CGSize nameSize = CGSizeFromString(@"DCE Speaks Up");
CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
if (feed.imageURL) {
    imageSize = CGSizeMake(470, 394);
}
float height = 80;
NSString *string = @"";
if (feed.message) {
    string = [feed.message stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
}else if (feed.story){
    string = [feed.story stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
}
if (string) {
    NSDictionary *attributes = @{
                                 NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody]
                                 };
    CGRect bodyFrame =
    [string boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(collectionView.bounds),
                                            CGFLOAT_MAX)
                         options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin)
                      attributes:attributes
                         context:nil];

    height += ceilf(CGRectGetHeight(bodyFrame));
}
return @{ @"imageHeight" : @(imageSize.height) , @"messageHeight" : @(height) , @"nameHeight" : @(nameSize.height)};
}
```

Custom cell file

```
@implementation FacebookCollectionViewCell

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self)
{
    self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    // change to our custom selected background view
    self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    self.messageLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    self.nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
}
return self;
}

-(void) setFeed:(FacebookFeed *)feed{
_feed = feed;
self.messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
self.messageLabel.lineBreakMode = 0;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSData *data= [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:feed.imageURL];
    UIImage *theImage=[UIImage imageWithData:data];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.imageView.image= theImage ;
    });
});
if (feed.message) {
    self.messageLabel.text =  [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[feed.message stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];
}else{
    self.messageLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[feed.story stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];
}
self.messageLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:11];
[self.messageLabel sizeToFit];
self.nameLabel.text = @"DCE Speaks Up";
[self.nameLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:12]];
[self.nameLabel sizeToFit];
}
-(void) layoutSubviews{
NSLog(@"%@",self.feed);
self.nameLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, self.contentView.bounds.size.width, [self.sizeDictionary[@"nameHeight"] floatValue]);
float height = 200;
if (self.contentView.bounds.size.height - [self.sizeDictionary[@"messageHeight"] floatValue] -[self.sizeDictionary[@"nameHeight"] floatValue] >100) {
    height = self.contentView.bounds.size.height - [self.sizeDictionary[@"messageHeight"] floatValue] -[self.sizeDictionary[@"nameHeight"] floatValue];
}
if (self.feed.imageURL) {
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(10, [self.sizeDictionary[@"messageHeight"] floatValue] +[self.sizeDictionary[@"nameHeight"] floatValue], self.contentView.bounds.size.width - 20,height);
    self.messageLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, [self.sizeDictionary[@"nameHeight"] floatValue] +10, self.contentView.bounds.size.width - 10, [self.sizeDictionary[@"messageHeight"] floatValue]);

    [self.contentView addSubview:self.messageLabel];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.imageView];

}else{
    self.messageLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, [self.sizeDictionary[@"nameHeight"] floatValue], self.contentView.bounds.size.width - 10, [self.sizeDictionary[@"messageHeight"] floatValue]);
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.messageLabel];
}
[self.contentView addSubview:self.nameLabel];

} 
@end
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a constraints issue, it doesn't appear you've added any programatic constraints.

Try something like this with your views, this is just an example of course, so to make the imageView hug the bounds you'd ideally set it to 0 on any side. Doing self.bounds or self.view.bounds.width/height etc. has never worked for me in cells so I always do it this way.

```
NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_yourImageView);

    NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[yourImageView]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];

    NSArray *horizontalConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[yourImageView]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];

    [self.contentView addConstraints:constraints];
    [self.contentView addConstraints:horizontalConstraints];
```

Comment: NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = @{@"imageView" : self.imageView,@"messageView" : self.messageLabel, @"nameView" : self.nameLabel};
    
    NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-10-[nameView]-5-[messageView]-5-[imageView]-10-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];
I changed the vertical constraints to this code, but the compiler says unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints and the messagelabel is overlapping on name label and the imageview is not coming at all

Comment: My fault, I missed that, I don't however see "translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO" anywhere, that always does it for me.

Comment: Basically, do "self.translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO" then also for each view, i.e. "yourView.translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO"... then let me know how it looks.